# Where have we used that $G$ is a compact Lie group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a topological space $X$.

> **I need to show that the orbit map $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ has the path
>   lifting property**.

Here is the proof -

Let $f:I\rightarrow X/G$ be a path in $X/G$. Let $G$ act trivially on $I$.

Consider $f^*X$ , the pullback of $X$ via $f$. That is $f^*X=\{(x,y)\in X\times I : p(x)=f(y)\}$. Let $p':f^*X\rightarrow X$ be the projection to first co-ordinate.

Then $f^*X$ has a natural $G$ action and the orbit space $(f^*X)/G\cong I$. Thus we have a section $\sigma:I\rightarrow f^*X$ (a section for the projection $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ is a continuous map $\sigma:X/G\rightarrow X$ such that $p\circ \sigma =id_{X/G}$)

So the map $p'\circ\sigma:I\rightarrow X$ is a lift of $f$ and we are done.

> **I don't see where we have used the fact that $G$ is a compact Lie group in this proof**

As I understand, we can define pullback or sections in the context of any topological group $G$ acting on a topological space $X$. Or am I wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the section $\sigma$?

Comment: For any $X$ and $G$ we can find a section $X/G\rightarrow X$ right? So here since $f(^*X)/G\cong I$ so we can have a section

Comment: No, you quite often can't.  For instance, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}$ acting by addition, there is no section.

Comment: Since $X\rightarrow X/G$ is surjective, for $[x]\in X/G$ and a choice of $x\in p^{-1}[x]$ sending $[x]$ to $x$ gives a section doesn't it?

Comment: That will not be continuous in general, as Eric's example shows...

Comment: A section is injective: if in Eric's example there were a section we would have a subspace of $\mathbb R$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong S^1$.

Comment: Oh I see! So I guess that is where the compactness is needed. I shall think about it. Thank you @EricWofsey and Mariano

Comment: Well: compactneess of $G$ does not guarantee that there is a section. For example, if $G=S^1$, viewed as a sbgroup of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb C$, acts on $S^3$, viewed as the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^2$, by scalar multiplication then the quotient map is $S^3\to S^3/G\cong S^2$ is the Holf fibration, and it does not have a section. (A simpler example is $G=\{\pm1\}$ acting on $S^1$ with quotient $S^1$, I guess)

Comment: What **is** true is that there are sections *locally* around every point of $X/G$, and that is enough to construct your lifting. (This is related to the existence of "slices" for the action,and this is much more delicate when the group is not compact (but it should hold when the the acion has compact stabilizers, I guess...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is Hausdorff then the path-lifting property for the quotient map $X\to G/X$ is Theorem 6.2 in G.Bredon "Transformation Groups". The theorem itself is attributed to Montgomery and Yang. The proof is nontrivial.

Comment: thank you for the reference. Theorem 6.1 tells me how to get the section I need for the proof in my question to make sense.